# Correct column name selections

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  blockchain.num_tx AS `num_tx`,
  blockchain.timestamp AS `timestamp`,
  GDELT.GLOBALEVENTID AS GLOBALEVENTID,
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CAST(GDELT.SQLDATE AS STRING)) AS SQLDATE,
  GDELT.Actor1Code AS Actor1Code,
  GDELT.Actor1Name AS Actor1Name,
  GDELT.Actor2Code AS Actor2Code,
  GDELT.Actor2Name AS Actor2Name,
  GDELT.AvgTone AS AvgTone,
  GDELT.SOURCEURL AS SOURCEURL
FROM
  w205_final_project.blockchain_data AS blockchain
INNER JOIN
  w205_final_project.GDELT AS GDELT
ON
  blockchain.timestamp = GDELT.SQLDATE
```

Return the following :

> Error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types:
>   TIMESTAMP, INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [18:3]

`GDELT.SQLDATE` column data is in integer format to begin with, as `YYYYMMDD`;
`blockchain.timestamp` column is in `timestamp` format to begin with, for example:

```
2015-01-01 04:29:21 UTC
```

Comment: What is the type of SQLDate?  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: SQLDATE is originally an integer. That line works fine; sqldate is cast as string and then converted to timestamp as I wanted. It's the blockchain.timestamp line that is giving me trouble. I want to join on these two timestamp formatted columns (the column named timestamp is indeed already in timestamp format) at the end.

Comment: Show error message! And show few examples of `GDELT.SQLDATE` and `blockchain.timestamp` - below links can help you - how to show [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with and  [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: done, thank you, looks like I'm not successfully converting SQLDATE to timestamp format. please advise :)

Comment: `operator = for argument types: TIMESTAMP, INT64` => ok this is what I explain in my answer, your join on your `(INT) GDELT.SQLDATE` not on the `(TIMESTAMP) GDELT.SQLDATE` you generate in your select, So the Join don't know what to do

Comment: can you explain why my cast to string method doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a BigQuery expert, but `SQLDAT(_PARSED)` is a field only generated AFTER the join in this query, you'll not find it as `SQLDATE(_PARSED)` in your `join` clause

You should switch your `GDELT.SQLDATE` to `PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CAST(GDELT.SQLDATE AS STRING))`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  blockchain.num_tx AS `num_tx`,
  blockchain.timestamp AS `timestamp`,
  GDELT.GLOBALEVENTID AS GLOBALEVENTID,
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CAST(SQLDATE AS STRING)) AS SQLDATE,
  GDELT.Actor1Code AS Actor1Code,
  GDELT.Actor1Name AS Actor1Name,
  GDELT.Actor2Code AS Actor2Code,
  GDELT.Actor2Name AS Actor2Name,
  GDELT.AvgTone AS AvgTone,
  GDELT.SOURCEURL AS SOURCEURL
FROM
  final_project.blockchain_data AS blockchain
INNER JOIN
  final_project.GDELT AS GDELT
ON
  blockchain.timestamp = PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CAST(GDELT.SQLDATE AS STRING))
```

---

Second point, don't name your column `timestamp`, it's a SQL keyword, it's reserved, same go for `time`, `date`, ... At least, try to rename your alias to something like `blockchain.timestamp AS`created`

And avoid naming your alias the same than your column :

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CAST(GDELT.SQLDATE AS STRING)) AS SQLDATE,
FROM blockchain_data AS blockchain
INNER JOIN GDELT 
    ON blockchain.timestamp = GDELT.SQLDATE;
```

Is not the same as :

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CAST(SQLDATE AS STRING)) AS SQLDATE_PARSED,
FROM blockchain_data AS blockchain
INNER JOIN GDELT 
    -- not what you want, but what you do, with error TIMESTAMP = INT64
    ON blockchain.timestamp = SQLDATE 
    -- what you want, but show ERROR column not fould
    ON blockchain.timestamp = SQLDATE_PARSED 
    -- Is the valid expression  
    ON blockchain.timestamp = PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CAST(SQLDATE AS STRING))
```